# Unusual ethernet behaviour on medium-length cable run

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, home-networking

Apologies if this is the wrong place for this question, I was tossing up between here, Server Fault and Electronics SE!

I'm trying to extend my home network out to my office at the end of my garden, eventually having a wireless access point out there. To that end I've run Cat6 from my touyer (a Technicolor TG589vac) to an ethernet socket in the office - a total run of 40-50m with a passive joiner half way, well under the 100m maximum in the spec. Unfortunately I can't connect to the rest of the network using this cable unless I do the following:

1. Plug a device into the ethernet port of the router using a short cable (I've been using my laptop on ~1m of cable) and allow it to connect to the network.
2. Unplug the device and quickly replug the long cable into the same port.
3. Any device connected to the long cable is now connected to the rest of the network.

This is only a temporary solution as at some point the device in the office will lose connectivity again and the above trick will not work for >24 hours. Power cycling the router has no effect on the time before it'll work again. When this happens I've tried the trick on different ports on the router but with no success.

I've also noticed that the PC in the office only connects if I use a 4-wire ethernet cable. None of the cables in the run are crossovers.

I'm not an expert on the physical side of networking so this behaviour seems very weird. I can appreciate that cheap routers might play fast and loose with the maximum length requirement but surely that would mean that long runs either work or don't. Has anyone every seen anything like this, or have any ideas for other things I could try?

Comment: Did you use a tester to see whenever everything is properly cabled? It might be that either side switches to crossover (MDI-X). Did you have a look at the passive join? Where is it placed and is it properly isolated? Why did you not use a continuous cable?

Comment: I didn't use a single cable as when I started running the cable I realised I couldn't use the path I wanted and needed to take a longer route through my attic. By then I'd already buried 10m of it in the garden and didn't want to dig it up again. I tested each section of the run in isolation as I installed it though. What do you mean by is the join isolated? Also, is there a way to check if one side has switched to crossover mode?

Comment: OK I've noticed another unusual thing, the PC in the office only works with a 4-wire ethernet cable (which I didn't even realise I had). 8 wire ones don't work. It's not a crossover cable though.

Comment: I would edit your comment into the question.

Comment: I'm wondering now if I've wired up the socket wrong and crossed over the brown/blue but left the green/orange straight through? Could that cause this behaviour?

Comment: How did you test the cable? Test all the way from one end to the other. If all the wires aren't in alignment, fix it. I don't understand "4 wire cable," are you talking about a telephone cord? There aren't any "4 wire" Ethernet cables. They are all 8 wires and all 8 wires should pass through from end to end in the same order, and all connections should be wired the same, either T568A or T568B standard.  It sounds like you might not have a proper tester if you are wondering if you crossed wires around.

Comment: I don't have an ethernet cable tester, I tested with plugging devices into each end of each cable and checking they could talk. I don't know the proper term for a 4-wire ethernet cable, but it's an ethernet cable with only the green and orange pairs present - presumably as those are the only ones needed for 10/100 connections.

Comment: Check for a split pair. Make sure you used solid-conductor cable, not stranded-conductor patch cable, for your long run. Make sure you used 8P8C connectors (both male and female) designed for solid conductor cable, not the ones for stranded conductor patch cable and not the hybrid ones that are bad at both. Ethernet is designed for 100m runs where most of it is a single piece of solid conductor cable, save for up to 3m of stranded patch cable at each end.

Answer (score 0):

If I assume you didn't know anything about the weather rating of the cable your cable is probably already damaged.

Did you really just bury plain wire?  Was it even the correct type?  For example Plenum rated. You should have buried a either a plastic or conduit pipe.

[https://www.amazon.com/CERTICABLE-OUTDOOR-UNDERGROUND-DIRECT-CONNECTORS/dp/B00GA4SIC2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00GA4SIC2)

This one is 200ft with ends.
[https://www.amazon.com/Outdoor-Waterproof-Ethernet-Direct-Shielded/dp/B002HFO8JA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002HFO8JA)

Even then you should have put pipe down first so you can just pull new cable through it, without digging up your yard.  Otherwise underground yard animals can chew on it, rain, and etc can ruin it.

Pipe:

```
       1. easy to replace the cable
       2. easy to pull more cables
       3. protects from water, and yard liquid.
       4. protects from gophers, and other digging animals.
       5. Plastic pipe is non conductive, and protects again stray electricity
       6. When you go to pound something into the ground like a tent post or etc you will know you hit the pipe.  Otherwise the stake will go right through your cable and now you have to dig up the yard anyway.
```

**You need to dig up your yard** again, maybe rent a trench digger, and **do it right** or you will hate yourself in a few years when the cable goes bad.

Because I like overkill, I would put 1 1/2 metal conduit with 1 1/4 pvc(or whatever fits) on the inside for its electrical shielding properties.